# Is there a way to implement a clickable label in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm searching for a way to make a special label that, when clicked on, opens a link to a web page. Is there a way to do that in kivy?

Comment: Try using [**`on_ref_press`**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label) using `ref` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a subclass of your Label and attach the event to it

```
class MyLabel(Label):
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if touch.is_touch:
        your_function()
```

[Label source](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html?highlight=on_touch_down#kivy.uix.label.Label.on_touch_down)

[MotionEvent source](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.input.motionevent.html#kivy.input.motionevent.MotionEvent)

Comment: Thanks a lot man, but can you show me how to do it in kivy language pls?

Comment: Just add this to your code with def indented and call your labels 'MyLabel' in kivy language.